# Issues compiling and installing

Tags: ubuntu-15.10

I am compiling a program from the source code as it is not currently packaged and have been able to install all of the needed libraries except for osm-gps-map. Every time I try, I receive the following message;
No package 'osmgpsmap' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables BRAINSTORM_CFLAGS
and BRAINSTORM_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.

I am running Ubuntu 15.10 Wily. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error message you show includes suggestions of how to fix the fault. What happened when you tried those suggestions? Also, please read [mcve].

Comment: I am unable to locate where I am to adjust the PKG_CONFIG_PATH variable. Would it be the configure file? Sorry, this is my first time attempting to compile like this.

Comment: Typically, a name like `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` would be an shell (environment) variable. Have you done a web search for it? Have you searched the packages documentation for the name? These things should have been discussed in your question, to show what you had done and what you had researched before asking here on Stack Overflow.